# Spyder how to Schedule python scripts to run in sequence

Tags: python, spyder

I have multiple python scripts that need to run in sequence. Please advice how I achieve this scheduling within spyder

```
I have script1 to run followed by script2. and they need to start everyday 8:00am EST and end/stop at 4:25pm EST only during business days/hours.
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do this from Python, use the built-in functionality that Operating Systems come with.

Let your pc automatically run the program using `crontab` (for [Linux](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) and [Mac](https://betterprogramming.pub/https-medium-com-ratik96-scheduling-jobs-with-crontab-on-macos-add5a8b26c30)) or `Scheduled Tasks` in [Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ic4lUiDTbVI).

Comment: Thanks you any pointers how i launch my script to run using spyder based on the crontab

Comment: Why do you depend on Spyder?